# display Dropdown in angucomplete-alt When I click on the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

please see this :

http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/

I am using the example 1.

how display Dropdown  When I click on the input ?

please see :

When I press "u" key. Dropdown  are shown. but i need When I click on the input Dropdown  are shown.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried specifying `minlength="0"` on angucomplete element?

Comment: I've tried but not worked.

Comment: Do you want to show the dropdown when you click the input field? Showing the all items? That's a pure dropdown rather than autocomplete. I'm the author of angucomplete-alt but it does not support such feature.

Comment: ghiden, it actually would be helpful! I have a case where I am using one autocomplete field to display the same type of object. But when certain filters are applied, I want my user to be able to see all the options based on that specific filter.

Comment: This work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604376/how-to-get-a-scrollbar-when-we-type-at-input-box-using-angucomplete

Comment: @ghiden it would be helpful for people with the necessity. This is the second time I needed this. It would be great and will add more value if you can implement this also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch angucomplete-alt's `onFocusHandler` like this:

```
  scope.onFocusHandler = function() {
    if (scope.focusIn) scope.focusIn()
    if (scope.minlength == 0) scope.showDropdown = true
  }
```