# How to get a scrollbar when we type at input box using angucomplete?

Tags: angularjs

I have done a program which does autocomplete using angucomplete statement.but iam unable to get when i enter any key it does not displaying it with scrollbar whne number of matches are done.CAn anyone help me to solve this

```
//Html file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Autocomplete using remote searching</title>

<script src="angularfiles/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angularfiles/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="angularfiles/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="Jsfiles/autourl.js"></script>
<script src="angularfiles/angucomplete-alt.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="angularfiles/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="angularfiles/angucomplete-alt.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="angularfiles/bariol.css" />
</head>

 <body ng-controller="controller">

    <angucomplete-alt id="members"  pause="400" placeholder="Type to start"
                            selected-object="testObj" maxlength="40" 
                         remote-url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address="
                        remote-url-data-field="results"
                        title-field="formatted_address" 
                        minlength="1"
                        discription-field="status"
                         />

</body>
</html>


//JSfile

var app=angular.module("myapp",['ui.bootstrap','angucomplete-alt']);
app.controller("controller",function(){

});
```

Comment: Provide more clarification. Its quite difficult to understand whats the exact query.

Comment: i mean once u try to execute that code.And type "and"  ,the content which matches it displayes as a dropdown..If we have number of matches its displaying lengthy.Instead of that a scroll ba must be appended...how can i do it ?

Comment: @VindyaVeer Since you are using `ui-bootstrap` why not use its `typeahead` directive instead of `angucomplete-alt`? I think it is easier to use.

Comment: Yes but i have already done using that.As i a new to angularjs i am using evrythng that possible which makes me to understand everything.So is there any solution for it ?

Comment: FYI..this code can't be executed as `script` and `link` tags are linked with local file. What i understand is that you need a scrollbar when you have a large number of records that matches the criteria. Am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show scrollbar, you need to set the following css style to angucomplete-dropdown class, and then the directive automatically picks it up.

```
.angucomplete-dropdown {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 200px; // your preference
}
```

See [example #1](http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/#example1)

For more Info: https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt